# Store dataframe to Google Cloud Plateform (GCP) in R

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am learning programming in R language and want to learn storage basics. I have created an R script that gets data from Google Analytics API and stores it in a local dataframe (on my own computer) to be able to apply new treatments to data. Now I'm looking for the right way to store this data on Google Cloud Storage to be able to access this data when I want.

These are the steps I imagine :

THE FIRST TIME I RUN THE SCRIPT

1. Get data from Google Analytics API and put it to a dataframe in R
2. Save this dataframe in .csv format (my_df.csv)
3. Send this csv to Google Cloud Storage

THE SECOND TIME (AND NEXTS) WHEN I WILL RUN THE SCRIPT

1. Get my_df.csv from Google Cloud Storage
2. Get data from Google Analytics API and put it to a dataframe in R (new_df.csv)
3. Merge new_df.csv and my_df.csv
4. Save this merged dataset as my_df.csv
5. Send my_df.csv to Google Cloud Storage (this way, it will replace the my_df.csv current version)

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Thanks in advance for your advices!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to store data frame to Google Cloud Platform in R?

Your approach seems fine to me, but if you would like to practice with Google Cloud products, I will recommend you the following:

For:

1. Get data from Google Analytics API and put it to a dataframe in R.
2. Save this dataframe in .csv format (my_df.csv)
3. Send this csv to Google Cloud Storage

If you are learning R, Python is also a great language in terms of Data Science or Machine learning, and it will open you a lot of possibilities within Google Cloud.

#### For Python's language

You could use Cloud Functions instead to execute this script. Some of the benefits of using Cloud functions are:

- Is the simplest way to run your code/scripts.
- It Automatically scales, highly available and fault tolerant.
- You are only paying only while your code runs.
- It Connects and extends cloud services, and it can be used with Cloud Storage, for example.

I attached you a [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python) on how to setup Cloud Functions with Python.

Also I will attach a good post [on how you can get Google Analytics data using Python.](https://www.mydatahack.com/how-to-get-data-from-google-analytics-reporting-api-with-python/)

As for executing the code automatically you could try to use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) which will let you run your code automatically whenever you would like to (in this case, the Google's Cloud Function that you will define early).

The alternative if you would like to use pure R, is to utilize `cron jobs` within a GCE instance, as I will explained later.

#### For R's language

You can set up a Google Compute Instance within [Google Compute Engine (GCE)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux). It has not to be a big machine, you can spin up a `f1-micro` instance for running your R code, and implement `cron jobs` to run your scripts at your desired date and time automatically.

[Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) you will find more information about adding cron jobs in Linux.

---

As for:

1. Get my_df.csv from Google Cloud Storage
2. Get data from Google Analytics API and put it to a dataframe in R (new_df.csv)
3. Merge new_df.csv and my_df.csv
4. Save this merged dataset as my_df.csv
5. Send my_df.csv to Google Cloud Storage (this way, it will replace the my_df.csv current version)

If you follow either of the proposed workarounds, **you will already have an automatic script running x times per week**.

You will not have to do neither of the steps 1 through 5 since the script will run and get a new dataframe with your Google Analytics data automatically.

Furthermore, you don't really need to rename your files with `new_df.csv` since Cloud Storage's objects support versioning, as shown [here.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) Therefore, you can overwrite the file that is already in the bucket after the merge process.

I hope this helps. Nonetheless, as I said before, your approach seems fine to me and it should work as you explained.